How to use Airflow XCOM to push and pull data and create tasks dynamically
I am trying fetch files from sftp and push them to s3 bucket,

fetching files from SFTP server and pushing them as df to xcom
if no files found using branch operator to skip the task
if files found creating each task for every file thats in the df

but unfortunately i am not able to create the tasks based on the df i run into this error

raise TaskNotFound(f"Task {task_id} not found")
airflow.exceptions.TaskNotFound: Task { not found

below is my defined dag and list_files is my method to fetch files from the server and push them as df
        df = pd.DataFrame({'file_names': files})
        print(df)
        ti.xcom_push(key='dataframe', value=df)

def decide_next_task(ti, server_name, **kwargs):
    server_files = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=f'list_files_{server_name}', key='dataframe')
    if server_files is None:
        print(f"No files found for {server_name}: {server_files}")
        return f'skip_task_{server_name}'
    else:
        print(f"Files found for {server_name}: {server_files}")
        return [f'upload_{server_name}_{file}_data_to_s3' for file in server_files['file_names']]


def create_upload_tasks(server_name, server_conn_id, directory_path, **kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    server_files = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=f'list_files_{server_name}', key='dataframe')

    if not server_files or 'file_names' not in server_files or not server_files['file_names']:
        return []

    upload_task_id = []

    if 'sftp' in server_conn_id.lower():
        for file in server_files['file_names']:
            upload_task = SFTPToS3Operator(
                task_id=f"upload_{server_name}_{file}_data_to_s3",
                sftp_conn_id=server_conn_id,
                sftp_path=f"{directory_path}/{file}",
                s3_bucket=s3_bucket_name,
                s3_key=f"{base_path}/{server_name}/{file}.csv",
                dag=ti.dag
            )
            upload_task_id.append(upload_task.task_id)
    else:
        for file in server_files['file_names']:
            upload_task = FTPToS3Operator(
                task_id=f"upload_{server_name}_{file}_data_to_s3",
                ftp_conn_id=server_conn_id,
                ftp_path=f"{directory_path}/{file}",
                s3_bucket=s3_bucket_name,
                s3_key=f"{base_path}/{server_name}/{file}.csv",
                dag=ti.dag
            )
            upload_task_id.append(upload_task.task_id)
    return upload_task_id


with DAG(
        dag_id='data_loading_server',
        description='Upload files from server to S3',
        schedule_interval='@weekly',
        on_failure_callback=airflow_callbacks.on_dag_failure,
        tags=["FTP", "SFTP", "export"],
        start_date=datetime(2023, 9, 21),
        catchup=False
) as dag:
    for server in servers:
        server_name = server['name']
        server_conn_id = server['server_conn_id']

        list_files_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id=f'list_files_{server_name}',
            python_callable=list_files,
            op_kwargs={'secret_name': server_conn_id},
            provide_context=True,
            do_xcom_push=True,
        )

        branch_task = BranchPythonOperator(
            task_id=f'branch_task_{server_name}',
            python_callable=decide_next_task,
            op_kwargs={'server_name': server_name},
            provide_context=True,
        )

        skip_task = EmptyOperator(
            task_id=f'skip_task_{server_name}',
        )

        create_upload_tasks_op = PythonOperator(
            task_id=f'create_upload_tasks_{server_name}',
            python_callable=create_upload_tasks,
            op_kwargs={
                'server_name': server_name,
                'server_conn_id': server_conn_id,
                'directory_path': server['directory_path']
            },
            provide_context=True,
            do_xcom_push=True,
            dag=dag,
        )

        list_files_task >> branch_task >> [skip_task, create_upload_tasks_op]

        upload_task_ids = '{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="create_upload_tasks_' + server_name + '") }}'
        create_upload_tasks_op >> [dag.get_task(task_id) for task_id in upload_task_ids]

